# Filter PostGIS DWithin center point SQL

Tags: postgis, postgresql, sql

Is there a way I can remove the center point from my results in a query like the following?

```
(select * from cities 
where l = true
and ST_DWithin(geography(cities.geog), (SELECT geog FROM cities WHERE cities.i = 'HNL'), 120000)
LIMIT 25)
UNION
(select * from cities 
where l = false
and ST_DWithin(geography(cities.geog), (SELECT geog FROM cities WHERE cities.i = 'HNL'), 200000)
LIMIT 5);
```

EDIT:
ah. this seems to work:

```
(select * from cities 
where l = true
and ST_DWithin(geography(cities.geog), (SELECT geog FROM cities WHERE cities.i = 'HNL'), 120000)
and geog != (SELECT geog FROM cities WHERE cities.i = 'HNL')
LIMIT 25)
UNION
(select * from cities 
where l = false
and ST_DWithin(geography(cities.geog), (SELECT geog FROM cities WHERE cities.i = 'HNL'), 200000)
and geog != (SELECT geog FROM cities WHERE cities.i = 'HNL')
LIMIT 5);
```

but is this the fastest way? I can probably swap out the sub-queries when I call this function from within express.js

Comment: Yes, try using a CTE, ie move the (SELECT geog FROM cities WHERE cities.i = 'HNL') to an initial WITH query. There may be other optimizations, it's a bit hard to tell what your query is trying to do, with the different LIMITS and search paramters to WITHIN.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you want to get all `cities` in the proximity of `'HNL'` (with your conditions), but not `'HNL'` itself I take it?

Try (with a CTE, as @JohnPowell mentioned)

```
WITH
  hnl AS (
    SELECT i,
           geog
    FROM   cities
    WHERE  i = 'HNL'
  )

SELECT a.*
FROM   cities AS a
JOIN   hnl AS b
  ON   ST_DWithin(a.geog, b.geog, 120000)
 AND   a.i != b.i
WHERE  l = true
LIMIT  25
UNION ALL
SELECT a.*
FROM   cities AS a
JOIN   hnl AS b
  ON   ST_DWithin(a.geog, b.geog, 200000)
 AND   a.i != b.i
WHERE  l = false
LIMIT  5;
```